# PHP and DOM to extract these specific data of a web page

Tags: php, dom, web-scraping

Using PHP and DOM how do I get the PLACE, ADDRESS, LOCALITY, REGION, POSTAL CODE and COUNTRY from the following code ( part of a web page ).

Since now I have developed a part of the code to get other content. This is the code so far.

```
$dochtml = new DOMDocument();
$dochtml->loadHTMLfile('');
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dochtml);

$descr = $xpath->query('//div[@class="description"]')->item(0);
    print_r($descr->nodeValue);

$abbr  = $dochtml->getElementsByTagName("abbr")->item(0);
    $title = $abbr->getAttribute("title");
    echo $title;
```

This is the rest of the code.

```
<div class="vcard location p">
    <div class="fn org">
        <a href="link here">PLACE</a>
    </div>
    <div class="adr">
        <div class="street-address">ADDRESS<br></div>
        <div>
            <span class="locality">LOCALITY</span>,
            <span class="region">REGION</span>
            <span class="postal-code">POSTAL CODE</span>,
            <span class="country-name">COUNTRY</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

I have a tiny problem with the following, in the page there are a lot of `<abbr>` tags however the two tags I want with classes `dtstart` and `dtend` as below are the only that are inside the `#eventDetailInfo`. Unfortunately, not all have the second `abbr` tag with the `class=dtend` so it gets the first from the "related events". So my question is how do I restrict it only to this specific id?

```
<div id="eventDetailInfo">
        <div class="p">
         <div><abbr class="dtstart" title="2012-07-16T21:00:00">Monday, July 16th, 2012</abbr></div>    
         <div><abbr class="dtend" title="2012-08-16T21:00:00">Monday, August 16th, 2012</abbr></div>    
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From reading the [`DOMXPath` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php), my suggested solution is outlined below.

**Get elements by class**

```
$nodes = $xpath->query('//div[contains(@class, "street-address")]');
```

**Get elements by ID**

```
$node = $xpath->query('//div[@id="someid"]');
```

**Solution**

To extract your values you could use something like ([working example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/1tBVMW)):

```
<?php
$html = '<div class="vcard location p">
    <div class="fn org">
        <a href="link here">PLACE</a>
    </div>
    <div class="adr">
        <div class="street-address">ADDRESS<br></div>
        <div>
            <span class="locality">LOCALITY</span>,
            <span class="region">REGION</span>
            <span class="postal-code">POSTAL CODE</span>,
            <span class="country-name">COUNTRY</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="eventDetailInfo">
        <div class="p">
         <div><abbr class="dtstart" title="2012-07-16T21:00:00">Monday, July 16th, 2012</abbr></div>    
         <div><abbr class="dtend" title="2012-08-16T21:00:00">Monday, August 16th, 2012</abbr></div>    
        </div>
    </div>
</div>';

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTML($html);
$xPath = new DOMXpath($document);

function extractNodeValue($query, $xPath, $attribute = null) {
    $node = $xPath->query("//{$query}")->item(0);
    if (!$node) {
        return null;
    }
    return $attribute ? $node->getAttribute($attribute) : $node->nodeValue;
}

$place = extractNodeValue('div[contains(@class, "fn")]/a', $xPath);
$address = extractNodeValue('div[contains(@class, "street-address")]',$xPath);
$locality = extractNodeValue('span[contains(@class, "locality")]',$xPath);
$region = extractNodeValue('span[contains(@class, "region")]', $xPath);
$postalCode = extractNodeValue('span[contains(@class, "postal-code")]', $xPath);
$countryName = extractNodeValue('span[contains(@class, "country-name")]', $xPath);
$start = extractNodeValue('div[@id="eventDetailInfo"]/div/div/abbr[contains(@class, "dtstart")]', $xPath, 'title');
$end = extractNodeValue('div[@id="eventDetailInfo"]/div/div/abbr[contains(@class, "dtend")]', $xPath, 'title');

var_dump($place, $address, $locality, $region, $postalCode, $countryName, $start, $end);
```

Output:

```
string(5) "PLACE" string(7) "ADDRESS" string(8) "LOCALITY" string(6) "REGION" string(11) "POSTAL CODE" string(7) "COUNTRY" string(19) "2012-07-16T21:00:00" string(19) "2012-08-16T21:00:00"
```

Comment: You have some space around `$place` because you have the `<a>` tag inside, and you don't select it.

Comment: Thank you for this great answer. Please take a look at my edit, I have posted one more thing on how to restrict the results from a specific id.

Comment: @Kaoukkos not entirely sure what you meant, but check my recent edit

Comment: Thanks again! I wasn't very clear, but I need to take the `2012-07-16T21:00:00` instead of the `Monday, August 16th, 2012`

Comment: @Kaoukkos updated `extractNodeValue` function to allow optional returning of attributes.

Comment: Great, I have accepted your answer, before giving you the +100, please tell me why when I echo something that originally has `<p><b><i>` tags in it's content, I get only plain text? I am referring to a `<div class="description"></div>` (I did this myself).

Comment: @Kaoukkos uh, there is no `div` with that class in your example? Try turning error reporting on: `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` to see if in fact you're getting errors?

Answer (score 0):

You were almost done with your code:

```
<?php

$dochtml = new DOMDocument();
$dochtml->loadHTML('<div class="vcard location p">
    <div class="fn org">
        <a href="link here">PLACE</a>
    </div>
    <div class="adr">
        <div class="street-address">ADDRESS<br></div>
        <div>
            <span class="locality">LOCALITY</span>,
            <span class="region">REGION</span>
            <span class="postal-code">POSTAL CODE</span>,
            <span class="country-name">COUNTRY</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>');

$xpath = new DOMXpath($dochtml);

$place       = $xpath->query('//div[@class="fn org"]/a')->item(0)->nodeValue;
$address     = $xpath->query('//div[@class="street-address"]')->item(0)->nodeValue;
$locality    = $xpath->query('//span[@class="locality"]')->item(0)->nodeValue;
$region      = $xpath->query('//span[@class="region"]')->item(0)->nodeValue;
$postalCode  = $xpath->query('//span[@class="postal-code"]')->item(0)->nodeValue;
$countryName = $xpath->query('//span[@class="country-name"]')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Live code [available here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/H8myIv).

Comment: Should check node exists before attempting to access `nodeValue`, else risk: `E_NOTICE Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in __FILE__ on line __LINE__`

Answer (score -1):

Use [PHPQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) or similar libraries if you know CSS selectors.

Comment: He's almost there with DOMXPath